# Is there a way to count dict keys of Mongodb subdocument?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
    _id: x,
    1: {a:a, b:b, c:b},
}
```

I want to count the number of keys in the dictionary `{a:a, b:b, c:b}` (which is 3 here).

My current solution **doesn't work**, as `$size` only works on arrays (and it looked pretty bad, even worse as it returns a cursor).

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match: {$and: [{_id: x}, {1.a: {$exists: True}}]}},
    {$project: {my_count: {$size: $1.a}}}
])
```

I suppose I could change the schema to an array, but this would not be very good for most of my operations.

Is there a way to do this?

*PS: I do not want to return the documents (millions of calls per second), I am trying to get the count only, from one query, in an optimized way if possible.*

*PPS: I am using (this cannot change) mongodb 3.2.x*

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do so directly in aggregation pipeline but MongoDB do support map-reduce which might be your life savor.

Comment: ‘map_ reduce’ is very slow and not meant for « millions of calls per second  ».

Comment: Millions of calls? Interesting. Probably MongoDB isn’t right choice.